# How to set 66% area to one element and 33% and 33% to the other two elements using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to set the `order id` on the very left and set the rest of the two to the very right of the div. The `total` and `view` elements should have equal space between them but should be to the right. `justify-content:space-between` sets equal space in between them and flex-grow or shrink is not working in my case. Am i doing something wrong? please help.

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-between" class="orders-table-header">
  <p class="orders-table-text text-center" style="flex-shrink:2">ORDER ID</p>
  <p class="orders-table-text text-center" style="flex-grow:1">TOTAL</p>
  <p class="orders-table-text text-center" style="flex-grow:1">VIEW</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If they have the same parent, I don't think they can get to 33% of width and staying in the same row. 
66% + 33% + 33%. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `The total and view elements should have equal space between them`...equal to what?...they are just two...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

You can't split into *66%+33%+33%* ,You could give `flex` 2+1+1

```css
.text-center {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-between" class="orders-table-header" style="display: flex;">
        <p class="orders-table-text text-center" style="flex: 2;background-color: aquamarine;">ORDER ID</p>
        <p class="orders-table-text text-center" style="flex: 1;background-color: bisque;">TOTAL</p>
        <p class="orders-table-text text-center" style="flex: 1;background-color: coral;">VIEW</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `margin` on flex items to align them `left` and `right`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

.orders-table-text {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.orders-table-text.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.orders-table-text.left {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-between" class="orders-table-header">
  <p class="orders-table-text text-center left">ORDER ID</p>
  <p class="orders-table-text text-center right">TOTAL</p>
  <p class="orders-table-text text-center right">VIEW</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your two right items into a div, `justify-content: space-between` will work as you are expecting:

```css
.orders-table-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.orders-table-text {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-between" class="orders-table-header">
  <div>
    <p class="orders-table-text text-center left">ORDER ID</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p class="orders-table-text text-center right">TOTAL</p>
    <p class="orders-table-text text-center right">VIEW</p>
  </div>
</div>
```